# how to get my WP site's IP?

Tags: redirect, domain, domain-mapping, dns

Built new web site on WordPress.
Added its domain to Network Solutions.
Need to know IP address of WordPress site to set the A RECORD on Network Solutions, which hosts the domain.

On WordPress.com cannot figure out how to look up the IP of my site there.
(And their chat is down for week.)

Comment: Hi Doug, this site is geared towards WordPress development and [WordPress.com issues are off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It looks like WordPress.com offers [other formats for support](https://en.support.wordpress.com/). Perhaps you can [try their forums](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a general hosting question, rather than WordPress.

Nonetheless, since you mentioned that you have your website on [WordPress.com](https://wordpress.com/), you can have your new domain point to your WordPress site by it's [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record). In your case, your CNAME would look be `example.wordpress.com` (change `example` to your actual site).

This is the recommended approach since using a CNAME rather than the A record because if WordPress.com changes your IP, the CNAME will alway point to the right one.

Otherwise, check out this article that WordPress provides to point your custom domain: [Use a Domain You Already Own (Domain Mapping)](https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-existing-domain/)